# Get name of property from its own function

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui

I would like to get the name of a property from within its own function.  My current approach does not work because the function is nameless.  How can I do this?

```
window.APP = {
    models: {
        ex_model: kendo.observable({
            ex_property: function () {
                var property_name = arguments.callee.name.toString();
                console.log(property_name);
            },
        }),
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: thanks for the votes; I have this question submitted to Telerik's support team and we have 24 hour response time subscription

Comment: they told me it can't be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make ex_property have a name. Instead of using `function()`, you can say `function function_name()`, and then `arguments.callee.name.toString()` would return `function_name`. Like this:

```
window.APP = {
    models: {
        ex_model: kendo.observable({
            ex_property: function function_name() {
                var property_name = arguments.callee.name.toString();
                console.log(property_name); // will return function_name
            },
        }),
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I realized this as well, thank you; but I'm trying to shave time off of coding (time = $$) and that would be an extra copy and paste, but still not bad